# Application.Current.Shutdown() vs. Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown()

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, shutdown, dispatcher

First a bit of background: I have a WPF application, which is a GUI-front-end to a legacy Win32-application. The legacy app runs as DLL in a separate thread. The commands the user chooses in the UI are invoked on that "legacy thread".

If the "legacy thread" finishes, the GUI-front-end cannot do anything useful anymore, so I need to shutdown the WPF-application. Therefore, at the end of the thread's method, I call `Application.Current.Shutdown()`.

Since I am not on the main thread, I need to invoke this command. However, then I noticed that the Dispatcher also has `BeginInvokeShutdown()` to shutdown the dispatcher. So my question is: What is the difference between invoking

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

and calling

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some more testing, and now I think I know the differences:

1) As stated in the MSDN page, `BeginInvokeShutdown`, besides shutting down the Dispatcher, also clears/aborts its queue. `Shutdown` first handles all items in the Dispatcher queue.

> Once the shutdown process begins, all pending work items in the queue are aborted.

2) In an application I can handle the [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) event. This event is fired when I call Shutdown, but NOT fired when I call BeginInvokeShutdown! The same applies to [Window.Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) and [Window.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx).

As for similarities, in both cases the main thread is exited. Depending on other running threads, this also shuts down the process: non-background threads are run to completion before the process exits.

Below is my test code. Comment one or the other method call in Application_Startup:

```
public partial class App
{
    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exiting");
    }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var testThread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send);
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Application.Current.Shutdown()));
            });
        testThread.Start();
    }
}

public partial class Window1
{
    public Window1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("One");
        }));

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Two");
        }));

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Three");
        }));

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Four");
        }));
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closed");
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN page for Shutdown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx)
[MSDN page for BeginInvokeShutdown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvokeshutdown.aspx)

It seems that this is just a collision of terminology. `BeginInvokeShutdown` shuts down that *dispatcher*, your application can in theory continue to live afterwards (though without a dispatcher, it'd be pretty limited). `Shutdown` however actually exits your application, which is what you want.

Comment: Well, that is precicely the question which isn't answered in the documentation: Does shutting down the application's dispatcher also shut down the application?

Comment: I built a simple WPF test application for this. To simulate your code, I did: `Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { Thread.Sleep(50000); })); t.Start(); Application.Current.Dispatcher .BeginInvokeShutdown(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);`. The Dispatcher shutdown killed its owner thread and closed the window, but did *not* kill the background thread.

Comment: Two small differences: 1) I call shutdown in the second thread (though through testing I can see that it makes no difference). 2) I have the second thread set as background thread (IsBackground = true). That way, it also gets killed if the main thread quits.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Daniel - our application is built in the same way - WPF front-end to a Win32 COM (Delphi) application running separately. It would be interesting to talk and compare our approaches.

But why I have stumbled upon your question is that our application used to call Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown, which worked fine with exception of a few cases where it did not terminate properly. When I finally got my hands on a machine on which this was reproducible, switching to Application.Current.Shutdown() fixed the problem. I still do not understand what was the problem.

Comment: I'd guess that is because the call to Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown() aborts/clears any pending messages. In my case, I also do a bunch of cleanup in the Window.Closing/Closed cases and Application.Exit (to shutdown the Win32 part).