# Shutdown an application running with a bootstrapper

Tags: c#, unity-container, bootstrapper

My application is launched with the following code:

```
public void StartUp(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Bootstrapper b = new BootStrapper();
    b.Run();
}
```

When I try to close the application in my shell (MainWindow) `Application.Current.Shutdown();` all windows are closed but the process of my application is still running.

How to close fully the application, process included ?

A little application as test with a simple bootstrapper associated to a call to the method Shutdown in the shell works.

I have other modules working with threads. Is it possible one module is still running in background ? So, how to also close it ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2942357/6830901

Comment: Ok, that works with the threads set in background (`IsBackground = True`).