# Preventing FileSystemWatcher throwing TaskCanceledException when calling Shutdown()

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a WPF application that checks whether a file has been modified within a certain period of time and if so, the application exits.

I am having an issue that the method that ultimately triggers the call of `App.Current.Shutdown()` is an event handler attached to a `FileSystemWatcher` event and causes a `TaskCanceledException` to be thrown.

A minimal working example is as follows:

Create a new WPF application.  In `App.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        FileSystemWatcher w = new FileSystemWatcher();
        w.Path = /*path to suitable test folder*/
        w.Filter = "Test.txt";
        w.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        w.Changed += (s, a) =>
        {
            //Shutdown(); --Throws InvalidOperationException (Calling thread cannot access this object)
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Shutdown());
        };
        w.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

Edit the file Test.txt and the application should close.

In order to prevent the exception showing, I can surround the shutdown call with a empty try-catch block

```
try
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Shutdown())
}
catch(TaskCanceledException)
{

}
```

but this seems to be a hack and doesn't solve the underlying issue.

It seems to me that C# is trying to tell me I am going about this the wrong way.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Interesting - I am using VS2015 on Win 10 and targetting .NET Framework 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special method in the dispatcher to invoke a shutdown: [`InvokeShutdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx)

Calling `Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();` from the `Changed` event handler avoids the exception.

This shuts down the dispatcher, which in turn leads to the shutdown of the application. There's some discussion on the difference between this and `Application.Shutdown` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942357/33080).

Comment: This works, thanks.  I'll wait a bit to see if there are any other opinions before accepting.